# What's the meaning of 我跟你学学他啊?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context, mandarin

Two girls are talking about how bad a guy was.
One of them said 我跟你学学他啊 then proceeds to imitate/repeat what the guy said.
When I look up 学学他, all I get is the meaning of learn or study which does not make sense in this context. 
"Let me imitate him for you" is my guess.

提前致谢

Answer (score 0, accepted):

学 does have the meaning of "to imitate"

鹦鹉学舌 doesn't mean "parrot learning tongue". It means "parrot imitate human tongue (language)"

我学他走路给你看 doesn't mean "I learn his way of walking and show you" It means "let me imitate him walking and show you"

'Learn from him" is 跟他学, not 学他

> 我跟你学学他啊

It does means "Let me imitate him for you" as you guessed

Answer (score 1):

学学他 means is Performance imitates his behavior.学学 Equivalent to imitation.